# Error _Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Programming.Recently I have been trying to work on adding a toolbar and tab bar to my existing Recycle view.However, after adding the elements, the Android Studio is suddenly complaining about the problem.

**Error.Execution failed for task':app:mergeDebugResources'** 
AND

**Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details**

**This error**

[image: The error]

After google search for a little bit, I have found most of the **solution** ,which is to **disable the APPT2 in the gradle.properties**.However, the solution didn't solve my problem.In fact, it is causing more problem.

**After disabling AAPT2**

[image: After disabling AAPT2]

**My AndroidMenifest file**

[image: My AndroidMenifest file]

**Recycler view**

[image: Recycler view]

**Build.grade(Module App)**

[image: Build.grade(Module App)]

**Build.gradle(Top build level)**

[image: Build.gradle(Top build level)]

Comment: double check if you miss out any tag closure in your `admin_create_project.xml`

Comment: It's solved ,thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add **`Toolbar`** **END** *TAG*. i.e **`/>`**

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    .........
     android:layout_marginTop="14dp"

  />
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Run`**.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout file .xml on line ending with 5 you are missing ending tag `/>` for toolbar.